# Evaluate same condition for two output values in same column

Tags: sql-server

How to evaluate the same condition for two different outputs.
for example:

```
select case
          when 1 = 1 and 2 = 2 then 'one'
          when 1 = 1 and 2 = 2 then 'Two'
       end
```

how to make this statement  to be executed for two times.
rest of the columns have the same data.
I tried in a couple of ways but did not have luck.
Thank you.

Comment: Please share how you try it?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, you want to use complex condition more the one time -

You can implement this by storing the result within `OUTER APPLY` (Or `CROSS APPLY`) field

Like this:

```
select case when condition.is_true = 1
            then 'one'
            else null
       end as one,
       case when condition.is_true = 1
            then 'two'
            else null
       end as two
from table_name
outer apply
(
    select case when 1 = 1 and 2 = 2
                then 1
                else 0
           end as is_true
)condition
```